# Testing App State Saving/Restoration on Device without Xcode Connected

Tags: ios, testing, device

I am saving and restoring my app's state by opting in (in the AppDelegate):

```
func application(application: UIApplication, shouldRestoreApplicationState coder: NSCoder) -> Bool {    
    return true
}
```

This works when I kill the app with the Xcode stop execution button after the app has been backgrounded.

But when I try to kill the backgrounded app on the device (by double tapping the home button and swiping the app up off the screen), then the app state is not restored when relaunched.

How can I quit out of the app on the device so that it will restore its' state? Or is it now only possible to test it using Xcode?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I received a response from an Apple engineer and they confirmed this is correct behavior. He wrote:

> ISTR that removing the app from the multitasking UI specifically disables state restoration, on the grounds that the user only does this when there’s something wrong with the app and thus it’s better to start from a clean slate.

He stated that the `exit` function may be used to test saving the background state:

> Have you tried calling exit?  It’s definitely not OK to do this in production code (see [QA1561](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1561/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007952)) but it’s fine to use while testing.

Other ways of testing it include restarting the device and updating the app.